# send email after custom status change : Admin

Tags: magento-1.9

I would appreciate if anybody can help me in sending email once the status of customer is changed from **PENDING - > APPROVED** from the Magento Admin Panel

I want to send to customer that your status is approved now.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've installed an extension to manage customer status.

In any case, you have to create an observer that will catch the `<customer_save_after>` event.
There, you should check the customer status and in the case it is **approved**, you can send a transactional email by `Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->send()` function loading the appropriate email template.